# Making a child div fill to the height of its container, without using any explicit heights

Tags: css, css-float

I have a menu bar that has some child elements (including an input box, 2 dropdown menus, and 1 link to show a divbox under the menu bar). http://jsfiddle.net/thapar/GLwRr/

The menu bar currently conforms to the height of the child element with the greatest height. I would like to have the menu bar's other child elements to also respect the height of the largest child element. However, unless I give the menu bar an explicit height, `height:100%` on any of the children doesn't work.

Is there any way to have the child elements fill the height of the menu bar without using explicit heights in pixels/em's?

Answer (score 0):

If your container is relative, and your children are relative, you can do that by using the top: and bottom: css attributes.

Check out this jsbin project for what I'm talking about. Most projects have a well defined head section that maintains its height, so this solution would work in that case. If your layout is completely dynamic, I'm not sure how you can do that without a javascript solution.

http://jsbin.com/onubed/1/

Answer (score 0):

Setting the CSS on the container to `display: table;` and the child elements to `display: table-cell;` may give you the desired result.